# create individual class variables of all column items in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, class

I have a data set which looks like this:

```
   ID   data    name
    0   225.3   player0
    1   185.0   player1
    2   291.0   player2
    3   231.8   player3
    4   337.8   player4
```

the column 'name' contains unique values.

I want to create an individual class variable for each data point in column "name" using the following class code:

```
class personName:
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data= data
```

There are 1000 plus unique values in the column "name" and i want all those values to have their own class variable, and the name of the class variable is the name in the column "name".

For example:

```
player0=personName('player0',225.3)
```

How do I automate to create data for all player names, as I did for 'player0'? Kindly help.

Comment: You can use a dictionary: `players = {}; players["player0"]=personName('player0',225.3)`

Comment: this is good, but if i use this, I will have to initialize all manually. Is there any way I can do this using a loop?